# When truncate HBase Table Splits get removed

Tags: hbase

I created a Table namely *DEMO_TABLE* and inserted some data, but I wanted to clear out that table for that,

> truncate "DEMO_TABLE"

But this removes all pre-splits given to that Table. Can Anybody explain this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using HBase 0.98 or greater version, you can use truncate_preserve command in HBase shell. This will retain the previous region boundaries defined by the pre-split.